# Where is information about hard/soft links stored?

Tags: filesystems, files, symlink, hard-link, inode

Where does the *nix system store information about number of hard links to a specific inode? I can't find any information about that. Everywhere what a hard link is but rarely a bit more advanced information that touches inodes related stuff.

An inode stores information about number of links but where does it get it from? Can I locate all the links (both hard and soft) by knowing only the inode number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hard link count is stored in the inode. It starts at 1 when the file is created, increases by 1 each time the `link` system call is successful, and decreases by 1 each time the `unlink` system call is successful.

The only way to find all the hard links to the same file, i.e. to find all the pathnames leading to a given inode, is to go through the whole filesystem and compare inode numbers. The inode does not point back to the directory entries.

Directories are a special case: their hard links obey strict rules. (Some unix variants allow root to bypass these rules at the administrator's peril.) The hard links to a directory are its `.` entry, its children's `..` entry, and one entry in its parent directory (the parent being the directory reached by the directory's `..` entry).

There is no way to find all the symbolic links pointing to a file. They could be anywhere, including on a filesystem that isn't mounted.

With GNU or FreeBSD find, you can use `find /some/dir -samefile /path/to/foo` to find all the hard links to the file `/path/to/foo` that are under `/some/dir`. With the `-L` option, you can find all the soft and hard links to that file. You can find an inode by number with the `-inum` predicate instead of `-samefile`.